Identify new element within a group: Pyspark
For every new element in a group( ordered by time) I want to identify if it matches with any of the previous elements in the group/is it a new element altogether. (based on string matching - Levenstein distance)
Input:
Grp. Value.  Time

Food    10
Car     20
Foods   30
Game    40

Output:
Grp. Value.  Time.  Output

Food    10     Type1
Car     20     Type2
Foods   30     Type1
Game    40     Type3

Tried using collect set over partition but was not able to achieve the desired.
I would like to have a non udf based solution because data size is fairly large
